# How can I use generalized regression neural network in python?

Tags: python, neural-network, regression

I'm trying to find any python library or package which implements [newgrnn (Generalized Regression Neural Network)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/newgrnn.html) using python.

Is there any package or library available where I can use neural network for regression. I'm trying to find python equivalent of the [newgrnn (Generalized Regression Neural Network)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/newgrnn.html) which is described here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the library neupy which solved my problem:

```
from neupy import algorithms
from neupy.algorithms.rbfn.utils import pdf_between_data

grnn = algorithms.GRNN(std=0.003)
grnn.train(X, y)

# In this part of the code you can do any moifications you want
ratios = pdf_between_data(grnn.input_train, X, grnn.std)
predicted = (np.dot(grnn.target_train.T, ratios) / ratios.sum(axis=0)).T
```

This is the link for the library: http://neupy.com/apidocs/neupy.algorithms.rbfn.grnn.html

Answer (score 1):

A more upgraded form is [pyGRNN](https://github.com/federhub/pyGRNN) which offers in addition to the normal GRNN the Anisotropic GRNN, which optimizes the hyperparameters automatically:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as MSE
from pyGRNN import GRNN

# get the data set
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data
y = diabetes.target 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(preprocessing.minmax_scale(X),
                                                    preprocessing.minmax_scale(y.reshape((-1, 1))),
                                                    test_size=0.25)

# use Anisotropic GRNN with Limited-Memory BFGS algorithm 
# to select the optimal bandwidths
AGRNN = GRNN(calibration = 'gradient_search')
AGRNN.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
sigma = AGRNN.sigma
y_pred = AGRNN.predict(X_test)
mse_AGRNN = MSE(y_test, y_pred)

mse_AGRNN ## 0.030437040
```